# WordPress: Error when open wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question is asked many times here. But none of the answers solved my problem.

When I try to log-in to my site through wordpress-admin, like this, `mysite.com/wp-admin` it gives me the error "This webpage has a redirect loop".

And Show `414 Request-URI Too Large`

one conclusion I came to, is, there is no problem with plugins. I tried changing the plugins directory name. It doesn't work.

I tried changing file permissions. It doesn't work.

Added the following code to .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  /wp-admin/ /wp-admin/index\.php [L,P]
```

It too doesn't work for me.

Please help me. What else can I do? Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you go directly to `/wp-login.php` to login with your admin credentials?!

Comment: its redirect me to homepage

Comment: It could be a theme. You changed the plugin dir, you can rename the active themes folder to reset to the stock theme.

Comment: i do that but still not work

Comment: What happens when you put a clean, default WP .htaccess file in? You say you've amended your version of the file, maybe you've made a typo on it? Also, can you put a list of the plugins you have installed?